# Will I get Search Ads Attribution data on pre-installed app?

Tags: ios, swift

As per Apple Search Ads, what will happen if the app is already installed on user device and user click on the app ad and open the app from App Store? Will I get the Search Ads attribution data?

As per Search Ads Attribution API I got the below question but did not get the answer [link](https://searchads.apple.com/help/pdf/attribution-api.pdf)

**How can I tell when I will get attribution data and when I will not?
Attribution data is available when the following is met:**

A user clicks on a Search Ads impression and either downloads or re-downloads the corresponding attribution-enabled app within
30 days of clicking.

Comment: iAd has been discontinued. Do you mean Apple Search Ads?

Comment: @DanielStorm yes sir

Answer (score 1):

If the user has installed the app from Apple Search Ads within the last 30 days the attribution data should be provided on every call to the Attribution API regardless of if the user opens the already installed app via Search Ads or via the home screen.

I developed the [Kitemetrics](https://kitemetrics.com/) client SDK and service which implements the Apple Search Ads Attribution API and provides the metrics and analytics to help interpret the data.